# why is htaccess is forcing page download instead of showing in browser in wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently had to re-install wamp and .htaccess caused the 500 error so I checked and turned on the mod_rewrite. Now, instead of showing the page it is forcing a download.  Further research indicated the problem might be with the headers mod so I turned that on but it is still forcing the download...

I downloaded the file, and the file being forced to download is not the same file I am attempting to view, but instead is the index file for the site i am working on.

At a loss... any help appreciated in advance.
Pete

Comment: Is the extension of the page you are trying to load associated with something that can handle it? (See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler)

Comment: the extention is .php On the htaccess I am using the Addhandler to for htm and html to be processed as php

Comment: You normally would want to have the handler for php in httpd.conf. Check if something is defined for php there. If not, add the handler for php in httpd.conf and restart Apache.

Comment: I could not find anything defined for php so I added AddHandler php-script .php to the httpd.config and restarted it and it did not do anything...

Comment: I edited my question after downloading the forced file... it isn't even the file I am trying to view

Comment: Then start from scratch and deduct where the actual problem is coming from. Remove your .htaccess file and see if the problem persists. If you are using a framework, try accessing a php file outside the framework and see if the problem is there. If not, then you have to dig into your framework. If the problem is even there, then you need to dig into your configuration and find out what is working, and what isn't.

Comment: I found the solution and answered it below... thanks @Sumurai for your help... pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Additional comment: I am in awe at getting a negative vote on the question. Happens quite a bit. I am under the impression that this site is purposed for getting assistance when you are having a problem with your programming to obtain a solution. I had even indicated in the question that I did, in fact, attempt to find the answer prior to posting. I read every alternatives that applied when you ask the question prior to clicking the button... they did not provide a solution. Was the negative because it was something I should of already known? go figure...

Comment: Besides a downvote, this question has also 3 close votes as "off-topic: questions about problems with code should include code in the question". Usually downvotes are just that, an indication that someone finds the question of sub-par quality. Don't view a downvote as a personal attack, but rather look again at your question and see if you might be able to improve it in some way. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/2209007) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Found the Solution:

1] mod_rewite needed to be turned on on httpd.config

2] needed to add: AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php  to the httpd.config instead of my previous attempt of AddHandler php-script .php

Thanks for the help @Sumurai it pointed me in the right direction.